# Success runs in dependent trials

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 260 business days in a year. We have 54 employees. Each
employee is required to bring donuts twice a year
on different days. Each employee chooses the two days at random, independently of the other
employees.  What is the probability that there will be 10 business days in a row where nobody
brings any donuts?  I found this intriguing  problem on reddit.com.

Using a quick-and-dirty approach,
I arrived at the approximate value 0.9727 for the sought probability. The argument is as follows.  The expected number of occurrences of 10 business day in a row without donuts is

$\lambda=251 \times\left(\frac{{250 \choose 2}}{{260\choose 2}}\right)^{54}$

Then I approximate the probability that there will be no 10 consecutive business days without donuts by $e^{-\lambda}=0.0273$. I wonder whether there are better approaches to this type of problems dealing with success runs in dependent trials.